# Eclipse WindowsBuilder - Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create form in Eclipse by using windows builder in Ubuntu. After creating the project, eclipse says that eclipse could not open the file editor. An expectation was thrown. To solve this I have changed the workbench but the result is still the same, getting the error.

It's working perfectly in Windows.

Eclipse Version: 3.8.1

Ubuntu 14.04.

Here are the codes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.updateSourceActions(SourcePage.java:140)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.handleActiveState(SourcePage.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.MultiPagesMode.showSource(MultiPagesMode.java:54)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.MultiPagesMode.create(MultiPagesMode.java:100)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor.createPartControl(DesignerEditor.java:87)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Possibly Eclipse bug [416797](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416797)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could tell me a solution for this bug?

Comment: I don't know anything more than is in the linked bug report

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the "window builder engine".

in Eclipse go to help/install new software
and enter http://archive.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201209281200/4.2/ 
in the "work with" field.
Tick all the downloads (including window builder engine) and let it restart eclipse.

//credit to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sun-java6/+bug/1201198

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm sorry to reply after a so long time. It's because I was far away from computer during this time for some reasons.